# Numerical diagonalization of Hamiltonian using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, eigenvalue, discretization, laplacian

I am trying to diagonalize the Bogoliubov-de Gennes Hamiltonian. The problem is that the Hamiltonian contains a Laplacian. This could be solved by using a discretized Laplacian

If I use a simple Hamiltonian (just the Laplacian) and use `eig(l1dd(...,...))` with `l1dd` the discretized Laplacian (2 and -1's) as in [https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/laplacian/laplacian.html](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/m_src/laplacian/laplacian.html), Then I get:

[image]

I expect a linear or quadratic dispersion ($\omega \propto k or k^2$), but I get neither. What could be the problem? It seems that `eig` does a good job, so probably `l1dd` is the problem?

Comment: If there is any comment on cross-posting, feel free to remove the other question on sci-comp https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/41051/numerical-diagonalization-of-hamiltonian (I cannot delete it apparently)